# Getting statistics of a textarea (words, lines, chars)

Tags: javascript

I want to count the number of words, chars and lines of a text area.
Here is my code:
Is this perfect for doing so?

```
function getStats() {
  var text = textarea.value,
    chars = text.length,
    words = text.split(/\S+/g).length - 1,
    lines = text.split("\n").length;
  return lines + " lines, " + words + " words, " + chars + " chars";
}
```

Any correction?

Comment: Where is `textarea` defined?

Comment: `docment.getElementById("textarea")`

Comment: If this is about how to improve code, and not a problem with the code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to post this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it may work fine, there're some more innate problem with how you're doing things.

First of all, you're using a global variable (or at least not a local variable). Your function has a dependency on the `textarea` variable, which is defined outside the function, and is therefore not flexible and harder to test. Instead, why not just accept a textarea element to check against? Or even better, instead of operating on an *element*, operate on a *string*? That'll make more sense conceptually (the statistics aren't of the element, but of its value), and creates more flexible code.

Second, your function is vaguely named. `getStats` ? Get stats of *what*? What are these stats? Are they the mean height of 24 year old males? Renaming the function to something more meaningful will improve it immensely.

Third, your function does two things: It both calculates the statistics for the textarea, and then formats them in a string. But what if instead of that string, you want it in a different format? Or just the line count, not anything else? Instead of returning a string, why not return a data structure (a simple object), with these statistics inside it? That way you can format the data in any way you want.

Fourth, your definition of a word is a bit...strange. Defining a word is difficult enough, and your definition says that `.` (and others) by themselves are a word, so `hello !` is made out of two words, not one. Is that correct?

Comment: yea you're wight. but would you pls tell me any idea on how to count words correctly?

Comment: That heavily depends on your definition of a word. The most basic would be globally matching against `\w+`, but then you have to ask yourself if "foo@bar.com" is one word, or is it three?

Answer (score 5):

```
function getStats() {
  var text = textarea.value,
    chars = text.length,
    words = text.split(/\s+/g).length,
    lines = text.split("\n").length;
  return lines + " lines, " + words + " words, " + chars + " chars";
}
```

The above code works fine. You can optimize the code a little bit by doing this:

```
   words = text.split(/s+/g).length
```

instead of

```
  words = text.split(/S+/g).length - 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `id` of `textarea` to the function.

```
function getStats(textarea) {
  var text = document.getElementById(textarea).value,
    chars = text.length,
    words = text.split(/\S+/g).length - 1,
    lines = text.split("\n").length;
  return lines + " lines, " + words + " words, " + chars + " chars";
}
```

Personally I would like to return `object` with chars, words and lines instead of string like

```
function getStats(textarea) {
    var text = document.getElementById(textarea).value;
    return {
        chars : text.length,
        words : text.split(/\S+/g).length - 1,
        lines : text.split("\n").length
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to do things to an element, *don't pass an id and select it that way*. It assumes two things: (1)the element has an id; (2)the element is in the DOM. Instead, accept the textarea element, don't select it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve above functionality using small JavaScript code,

Please have a look on this link: www.jsfiddle.net/MrbUK/

Reference Link: http://textmechanic.co/Count-Text.html

For Number of Line counting: 
  Textarea.value.split(/\n/).Length

Comment: You can combine code above link result , Get your expected output.